# How to disable same origin policy in Chrome v81

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

It was working before but with the latest Chrome update (version 81), I can't log in to my web app locally.

Console error is:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Fiddler says its a 504 Receive Failure error

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and discovered that it was caused by the "Adblock" extension (my best guess is that it's because I had the words "banner" and "ad" in the filename).

As a quick test to see if that's your problem, start Chrome in incognito mode with extensions disabled `(ctrl+shift+n)` and see if your page works now. Note that by default all extensions will be already disabled in incognito mode unless you've specifically set them to run (via chrome://extensions).

OR

For disabling  same origin policy:

Close chrome (or chromium) and restart with the `--disable-web-security` argument. I just tested this and verified that I can access the contents of an iframe with src="http://google.com" embedded in a page served from "localhost" (tested under chromium 5 / ubuntu). For me the exact command was:

**Note : Kill all chrome instances before running command**

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="[some directory here]"
```

The browser will warn you that "you are using an unsupported command line" when it first opens, which you can ignore.

From the chromium source:

```
// Don't enforce the same-origin policy. (Used by people testing their sites.)
const wchar_t kDisableWebSecurity[] = L"disable-web-security";
```

Before Chrome 48, you could just use:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```